# How to print a series of natural no.s in the form of two Pyramids , one normal and one inverted using single for loop?

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop

I am trying to generate this kind of pattern which is based on user input .Here input is *num=7*

**Output**

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

To achieve this ,I came up with this **code :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test
{
public static void main(String arr[])
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a no to print a symmetrical pyramid :");
    int num=input.nextInt();

    //Printing normal Pyramid

   for(int i=0;i<=num;i++)
   {
       for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
       {
           System.out.print(j); 
       }

       System.out.println("");   
   }
    //Middle 
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    //Printing inverted Pyramid

    for(int i=num;i>=0;i--)
    {
       for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
       {
           System.out.print(j); 
       }

       System.out.println("");

    }

}
}
```

**How can I achieve the same output using only 1 for loop ?**

Thanks in Advance !! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. You should read [ask].

Comment: Put all the code on one line.

Comment: @Amit : Pardon me for not being specific

Answer (score 2):

You could use StringBuilder and add/remove in a loop

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<=(num*2)-1; i++) {
    if (i<num) {
        sb.append(i+1);
    } else {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Smart solution :)

Comment: For simple and nice logic :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is VB, but you should get it...

```
Dim yourNum As Integer = 9
Dim y As Integer
For x = 0 To (yourNum * 2 - 2)
    y = (yourNum - 1) - x
    For i = 1 To yourNum - If(y < 0, y * -1, y)
        output += i
    Next
    'write output
Next
```